# How to execute a script file in netezza?

Tags: netezza

I have a .sql file which i need to run from SSIS. But before running them in SSIS i need to run it outside the SSIS . Please let me know how to execute this file.
and also what to check if declaration of variables work in the external script. ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of an SSIS expert, but running .sql scripts is easily done with nzsql.exe

Most of our automated jobs run by generating large .sql files with Informatica powercenter (a tool much like ssis) and then execute these with nzsql.

All looping and branching is done while generating the file before the nszsql is started, since you cannot use such constructs outside a stored procedure in Netezza. In that respect it is very different from SQLserver...

I hope you can follow me?